# $_FILES not getting submitted file

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to have a form wherein people can submit files to be uploaded and subsequently linked into a mySQL database.

In the html/php file:

```
<form enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="process_file.php"  method="post" >
               <!-- First/Last Name input boxes -->
               <p>
                  <label for="fileUpload" id="fileUploadLabel">Proposal File (5MB Maximum):</label>
                  <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" id="fileUpload" />
               </p>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
            </form>
```

And the process_file.php file:

```
<?php
     require("../../include/utility.php");
     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        print_r($_FILES);
              $dbconn = connectToDB();
              // Get and clean the data.
              $fname = cleanInput($_POST["fname"]);
              $lname = cleanInput($_POST["lname"]);
              $new_filename = str_replace(' ','', basename($_FILES['fileupload']['name']));
              $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

              printf("File name: $new_filename <br />\n");

              $target_dir = "../proposals/2016";
              $target_file = $target_dir . $lname . "_" . $fname . "_proposal" . $imageFileType;
              printf("File Type is: $imageFileType <br />\n");
     }
     /* [REDACTED] */
 ?>
```

The print_r($files) always gives me "array()". I've looked around online over the weekend and quite a bit of today to no avail.

I've checked the enctype, I've checked the spelling, the capitilization, adding/removing the "[]" and anything else I could think of.

I know it works with the server's settings since others on the same exact server have been able to get this to work.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is not working? (I can provide more out of the [REDACTED] section, but since $_FILES is empty the code doesn't work anyways.

Comment: what are theses ”””””””””””” ””””””””””””” ?

Comment: `”multipart/form-data”` don't code with Word.

Comment: and `fileUpload` != `fileupload`

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. Either you held the * key too long or whatever you said got censored.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: the are evil Satan quote marks, not real quote marks, that's what they are

Comment: I never saw the mistaken " 's before. Crud. That is what I get for trusting the OCR of Firefox's PDF text selector.

Comment: OCR ?!? where are you sourcing your code from?

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. Ever have one of those days?

Comment: Nope, i use an IDE that would scream at me if i was ever *that* stupid ;-)

Comment: I'm using Atom, I just didn't notice the issue. (Yes, I know Atom isn't an IDE but a text editor but for web development work it suits what I need.)

Comment: *"Ever have one of those days?"* - Yep!

Comment: Btw, if `2016` is a folder, this `$target_file = $target_dir . $lname` will translate to `2016FILE.xxx` instead of probable intended `2016/FILE.xxx`. So if that's the case, then you need to add a slash to it `proposals/2016/`. Or you can do `$target_file = $target_dir . "/". $lname`

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code:

`”multipart/form-data”` - Those curly quotes are choking your script.

Those should have been regular `"` quotes:

`"multipart/form-data"`

Then your file input holds this name attribute `name="fileUpload[]"` yet, you're using `$_FILES['fileupload']` where the array is in complete lowercase.

Arrays are case-sensitive and should have read as `$_FILES['fileUpload']`.

I also noticed that and if `2016` is a folder, this `$target_file = $target_dir . $lname` will translate to `2016FILE.xxx` instead of probable intended `2016/FILE.xxx`.

So if that's the case, then you need to add a trailing slash to it `proposals/2016/`.

- Make sure that all folders have proper permissions to be written to.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.